# Stata: Changing Number Format

Tags: stata

I am using estpost and esttab to export tabulation results in Stata.

```
sysuse auto, clear
estpost tabulate turn foreign
esttab ., cells("b(fmt(0))") unstack 


---------------------------------------------------
                      (1)                          
                                                   
                 Domestic      Foreign        Total
                        b            b            b
---------------------------------------------------
31                      1            0            1
32                      0            1            1
33                      1            1            2
34                      2            4            6
35                      2            4            6
36                      1            8            9
37                      2            2            4
38                      1            2            3
39                      1            0            1
40                      6            0            6
41                      4            0            4
42                      7            0            7
43                     12            0           12
44                      3            0            3
45                      3            0            3
46                      3            0            3
48                      2            0            2
51                      1            0            1
Total                  52           22           74
---------------------------------------------------
N                      74                          
---------------------------------------------------
```

Although I can change the format of the cells, I couldn't find a way to change the format of the observation number(N) and the total number of observations in each column. I tried adding `obs(fmt(%10.2fc))` as an estab option but it didn't work.

Comment: There is no such option as you've discovered. Otherwise I can't see a way to add decimal places to display of what is usually (always?) an integer. You may get a better answer.

Comment: I want to insert commas into large observation numbers. I agree that decimal places don't make sense as the number of observations is always an integer.

Comment: 10.2 wouldn't insert commas, but I see why you want that.

Comment: You are right Nick. I edited that. Thank you

Comment: How many of these tables do you want in your real problem? 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... ? I see the solutions as just possibly (a) a smart way to do this in `esttab` (an excellent command I never use) (b) editing by hand (c) writing a program to read in the table text and editing it.

Comment: You are still asking for 2 d.p.!